# CMake: target_include_directories() can't find header files

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

At the top of my `main.cpp` file, `No such file or directory` is thrown at `#include <sqlite3.h>`.

Building the code manually by `g++ -I"C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\include\" -L"C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\bin\" -lsqlite3 main.cpp Class1.cpp Class1.h Class2.cpp Class2.h -o main` throws no errors.

CMake cannot seem to find the header, even though I've explicitly described where it is located in my file-system. According to the documentation for [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_include_directories.html), that should be enough:

> Specified include directories may be absolute paths or relative paths. Repeated calls for the same  append items in the order called.

**Why is the `target_include_directories()` function not finding the headers, even though I've provided the exact absolute path?**

I'm developing on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine, and CLion is set-up to compile with the MinGW-w64 `g++` compiler.

- I've downloaded the 64-bit Windows pre-compiled binary, `sqlite3.dll` and stored it locally in `C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\bin\`.
- In order to access SQLite C++ functions I've also downloaded SQLite3's amalgamated source code and stored all source files in `C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\include\`.

I built my project in CLion, which is essentially a fancy GUI-wrapper for CMake. In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I've included SQLite3's headers and linked `sqlite3` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(My_Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS C:\\Libraries\\64_bit\\SQLite3\\include\\)
set(LIBRARIES sqlite3.dll)
# My project's source code
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Class1.cpp Class1.h Class2.cpp Class2.h)

add_executable(My_Project ${SOURCE_FILES})

# For compiler warnings
target_compile_options(My_Project PRIVATE -Wall)
# Including SQLite3's headers
target_include_directories(My_Project PRIVATE ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Linking against sqlite3.dll
target_link_libraries(My_Project ${LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: CMake uses `/` as directory separator internally. Can you try with that instead of `\\`?

Comment: @Angew Just tried that, it didn't change anything. Still, good to know - I assumed the file separator would be system-dependent.

Comment: The whole point of using CMake is to be system-independent.

Comment: If you run a build manually (without CMake) with using `-I` (or equivalent flag) with the same path, does it build?

Comment: @Angew Running the command `g++ -I"C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\include\" -L"C:\Libraries\64_bit\SQLite3\bin\" -lsqlite3 main.cpp Class1.cpp Class1.h Class2.cpp Class2.h -o main` compiles the code successfully. No errors thrown. Edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: If in the background CMake produces a Makefile, try `VERBOSE=1 make` to see which command is being called. Also, try setting your path for INCLUDE_DIRS between quotes `"`

Comment: @VladislavMartin This is not in the CMakeLists.txt, it would be after executing CMake. It depends what CMake generator you use. I don't know if it works under Windows; how do you compile your project after executing CMake?

Comment: @oLen I think the problem with `target_include_directories()` was that I didn't use `"`s around my path. I had to make some additional changes so that CMake could find `-lsqlite3`, but the project is building successfully now! Thanks a lot. If you write an answer, I'll edit it to add the additional changes I made.

Comment: It's because cmake is a horrid piece of trash,  Same problem, two years ago, never worked after playing 20 questions on here.  Ditched it completely. All better.  (Double quotes didn't work for me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run into problems if you don't put paths between quotes.

Thus it is a good idea to write:

```
set(INCLUDE_DIRS "C:\\Libraries\\64_bit\\SQLite3\\include\\")
```

or, rather:

```
set(INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Libraries/64_bit/SQLite3/include/")
```

Additionally, the `CMakeLists.txt` as it currently stands won't be able to find `-lsqlite3`. Thankfully, CMake makes finding libraries easy:

```
# Optionally, add 'PATHS "C:/Libraries/64_bit/SQLite3/bin/"'
find_library(SQLITE3_LIBRARY NAMES sqlite3)
```

If the library is discover-able on your system, the above command will return the path to the library and store that path in `SQLITE3_LIBRARY`. All that remains to do is link the project against the SQLite3 library:

```
# Link project to the SQLite3 library
target_link_libraries(MSP_Tool ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Edited to include the additional bit I figured out on how to find the `.dll` now that the header files are taken care of (as per your answer, which is all my question asked for). Accepted :)

Comment: I've been messing with CMake for 2 days and all I missed was just double-quotes!? Thank you man!!!